# How to determine if built in web cam is broken

Tags: windows, windows-10, webcam

This laptop has a web cam but Skype does not seem to see it. I even looked at device manager and there are no imaging devices listed. I tried to also use the Windows 10 camera app and it claims the camera is busy.

The system is brand new. Is this a hardware issue?

Comment: If there is no imaging device listed in device manager, I would start with your laptop manufactures website and see if there is a driver for it.

Comment: I looked and saw no signs of a web cam driver

Comment: Dang. What's laptop do you have?

Comment: If it is brand new, you should be talking to the manufacturer for a warranty claim, not us. They will walk you thru the troubleshooting to verify it is bad. Anything we suggest and/or you attempt without contacting them first might void your warranty.

Comment: @FrankThornton If you open the Camera, does that program see it, if so then I have the solution to your problem

Comment: It just says that the camera is busy and can't be used

Answer (score 1):

Did the laptop have a shortcut keyboard with a camera symbol with it ? if so maybe your laptop locked the camera feature, the lenovo manufacturer often have a camera button to turn on/off

Answer (score 0):

Who is the manufacturer of your laptop?

Have you installed the latest Win 10 updates?  Typically does this upon first load of OS.

Could very well be something needs to be enabled to make it work, which is odd... OOTB it should work!  :)  One would hope... I've encountered stranger, especially with Dell machines.

Something to try that won't void your warranty:

Click the Windows icon, type System Configuration and open that.  Click the Services tab.  Sort by clicking the Status column header. Scroll through and see if there's anything Stopped related to a webcam AND/OR Skype- if anything related to those has "stopped" next to it, select the checkbox(es) and click "ok" to enable.  It will probably ask if you want to restart the computer, which is probably best, so close anything else you have open and reboot when prompted.  See if that helps.  Good luck.